# Can't connect to VPN in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, vpn, pptp

This is the procedure I followed:

Go to `System Settings > Network > Add VPN Connection`

Set in the dialogs that appear:

`Interface = "VPN"`

`Connection Type = "PPTP"`

Set the following params (as found [here](http://freevpnaccess.com/)):

`Gateway: 67.212.175.123`

`User name: freevpnaccess.com`

`Password: ****`

In advanced settings:

What all I left checked:

- CHAP
- MSCHAP
- MSCHAPv2
- EAP
- Use P2P encryption (MPPE)
- Allow stateful encryption
- Send PPP echo pakcets

(I unchecked everything else)

Then I go back to network settings and turn on my new VPN connection.

Nothing happens. No notifications.

My IP address is still the same on Google.

I click the Wifi symbol on the top bar of nautilus and hover over `VPN connections`.

I can see my new VPN connection but it is **grayed out** and I can't click it.

Please help me troubleshoot this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the above link.

The configuration you are using din't work for me  but

`Gateway: 83.170.84.216` worked for me.

Also in the "Advanced ..." check the "Use Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)" option.

Comment: I tried that address. But again nothing happens. What do you see when you, after creating the VPN connection, connect to it in the network manager (I mean, turn it on)? What am I doing wrong? :/
Did you restart your system?

Comment: These setting are working randomly. See here http://i.imgur.com/wkrEZwl.png